# some clarification about what an image recognition cnn should return on prediction

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

based on the examples of cats and dog recognition I created a cnn with tensorflow and keras that should recognize 4 classes of images: cats, cars, people, flowers. When I make a prediction the model responds with a list like `[0. 1. 0. 0.]` Is it correct or should it respond with a list of values between 0 and 1 of which I must take the maximum?
For example [0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8]

Comment: Generally, at least at the beginning of the training it should return a more spread-out prob distribution (not 0s and 1s). But this can be problem-dependent too. It's difficult to say what's going on without knowing more details.

Comment: if you need I can put the whole code although it seems a little long to me

Comment: Yeah, it's tough what to ask in this case. Maybe give a step by step breakdown of what you tried?

Comment: Please share the model.summary() along with the optimizer, loss function you are using. Its difficult to say without the information of the layers of the model.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have used softmax, log_softmax or sigmoid as last layer, below is how your output will look. I have given the math behind the computation and some explanation in the comments of the code snippet.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# Assume below is the input to last layer
Input = tf.constant(np.array([[0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1.5]]))

with tf.Session() as sess:
   # Computes softmax activations. softmax = tf.exp(logits) / tf.reduce_sum(tf.exp(logits), axis)
   # Output sums upto 1, as this is the probability
   print(tf.nn.softmax(Input).eval()) 

   # Computes log softmax activations.For each batch i and class j we have logsoftmax = logits - log(reduce_sum(exp(logits), axis))
   # Gives log(softmax(input)) as output which is log likelihood and value doesn't sum up to 1.
   print(tf.nn.log_softmax(Input).eval()) 

   # Computes sigmoid of x element-wise. Specifically, y = 1 / (1 + exp(-x)).
   print(tf.nn.sigmoid(Input).eval())
```

Output -

```
[[0.12872618 0.15722651 0.1920369  0.52201041]]
[[-2.05006775 -1.85006775 -1.65006775 -0.65006775]]
[[0.52497919 0.57444252 0.62245933 0.81757448]]
```